# Binding dynaminc columns to ASPxGridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, devexpress

I have *ASPxGridView* with 2 static columns and dynamic columns.

I set auto generated field to true, and bind the dataset with (12 columns) to *ASPxGridView*.

Grid shows 2 static columns only. I need to set dynamic column values as hyperlink field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true and add column to Columns collection, grid will render only column from Columns collection. You can try add static columns from code using `DataBound` event like in this sample:

[ASPxGridView - How to add a column if the AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3587.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, It's working. Then How to make the row item to hyperlink field?

Comment: You can use GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataHyperLinkColumnMembersTopicAll

Comment: I added GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn dynamically to grid. How to handle the hyperlink button in server side. i dont want to set the url to hyperlink. while clicking the hyperlink, i need to show the inner grid of the particular cell. how to do this?

Comment: @Pooja, please create another question and consider posting relevant part of your code in it. Comments are not the right place for additional questions.

Comment: column collection should only be modified during page_init event, otherwise filtering, sorting, and paging will throw index out of range error after resizing a column.